# Timer to throw Method Once a Week - C#, Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I'm fairly new to C# and coding in general. I'm looking for an example/open source Timer Function that will be used to throw a basic method (ex. Email Notifications) once a week at a certain time. After doing some research I've found that using a Timer instead of a Windows Service would be wise as it will have a very small workload.

I've found a couple timer API's on CodePlex and Code Project but am having trouble working my way through the Examples due to my minimal knowledge of C#.

Does anyone know of a Simple timer that I could use that is Beginner friendly and that also has a walk through? Or is there a simpler way of doing this using System.Timers?

My end goal is to have a timer that will fire a Method at 8:00AM every Monday.

EDIT: I believe I should have been more detailed in my initial Post. The reason I chose not to use the Windows Task Scheduler is because the Method I am invoking is more complex than just invoking Windows Task.

When the timer hits the scheduled time it will fire a Method which queries the DB for Items requiring service within a certain time-frame. This will then loop through the items adding them to an email which will be sent to that Warehouse's Admin.

If I'm not mistaken, that cannot be done through Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: are you planning to have an application that runs 24/7? Have you considered using Windows Planned Tasks?

Comment: May I suggest scheduled tasks? This is _exactly_ what they are for, and you don't need any C# for that. You can configure a new scheduled task entirely in the Windows UI.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a task scheduler, like the one built into windows...

Comment: I'll be honest and say I've never used C#, but in Java you can get the current system time. I would make a timer that wakes every few minutes and checks the current system time against its preset go-time (Monday 8am) and if it matches within a range (1 minute) it fires, otherwise it sleeps. Realistically, 1 week is a massive single timeout.

Comment: You speak about workload of windows services, but can you clarify what kind of application are you writing? If you are writing a windows application how can you be sure it will always be running at monday morning even if no user is logged in? I think you should rely on scheduled tasks of windows and make a small executable which does the job and let windows call it for you so you avoid all the pain. Or you make a windows service.

Comment: **Oh no!** I'm currently supporting the application which was written exactly this way. Please, never do it.

Comment: Lando please paste the source of your finding about using timers instead of Windows Service.

Comment: @Davide maybe it was whoever wrote gaearon's application

Comment: Response to edit: Of course you can use Windows Task Scheduler for this. The only function of the scheduler is to execute a task. There are no rules as to the complexity of the task it executes. Plus, querying a DB and sending an email isn't exactly an overly complex task. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a timer for this makes no sense. Your goal is to have a function fire at a specific time. What if your server reboots? Is your timer going to calculate the exact time between the reboot time and Monday at 8:00 am?

IMO, use a console application and the Windows Task Scheduler.

**Response to edit**: Of course you can use Windows Task Scheduler for this. The only function of the scheduler is to execute a task. There are no rules as to the complexity of the task it executes. Plus, querying a DB and sending an email isn't exactly an overly complex task. :)

Comment: Absolutely! I'm currently maintaining legacy app which is a windows service running 24/7 only to execute a method several times a week, and it's a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) for cron jobs.
This works on a hosted platform as well, where you have no access to windows services.

What you are looking for would be trivial to achieve.
Look at the first example from their [tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_1.html).

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_1.html

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree with your research and would place it into a Console Application that was run by the Windows Scheduler instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you you are fairly new to coding, the easiest thing to do would be to create an application (console based c# application would work the best) and use

> Task Scheduler

that's built into windows to launch the app 8:00am every monday.

Answer (score 0):

A cron job would be a much better option. What would happen if your website is down at 8 AM Monday morning? With cron, as long as the server is running it can execute your request.